# Applying a javascript function on a div

Tags: javascript, html, inheritance, dojo

I want to put a variable on a div and to be applied and inherited by all the dojo widgets under this div.

Is this feasible ?

For example

```
<div shaper="Contextual"> 
<textarea ..../> 
<select multiple data-dojo-type="dijit/form/MultiSelect"> 
.... 
</div>
```

I want the functionality supported by the shaper to be applied to all the widgets included in the div.
p.s.: "shaper" is a custom module created to do numeric shaping for Arabic numbers.

Comment: what you tried so far? can you post some code?

Comment: you can use data attribute

Comment: For example <div shaper="Contextual"> <textarea ..../> <select multiple data-dojo-type="dijit/form/MultiSelect"> .... </div> .. I want the functionality supported by the shaper to be applied to all the widgets included in the div.

Comment: and what is the shaper? `Contextual`? Is this a custom dojo module? You will have to explain it further and post the code you tried, because if you post a question of a single sentence, you can expect an answer of a single sentence.

Comment: ok..I edited the post.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, but not out of the box.

You can write something like this:

```js
require(["dojo/query", "dojo/domReady!"], function(query) {
  query("[shaper]").forEach(function(shaper) {

  });
});
```

This will query all elements with a `shaper` attribute and loop over it. Inside the loop, you will have to retrieve the value of the `shaper` attribute (for example `Contextual`), you can do that with the [`getAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) function, for example:

```js
var shaperModule = shaper.getAttribute("shaper");
```

Now you have the name of the module to load, so you can write something like this inside the loop:

```js
require([shaperModule], function(shaperModule) {

});
```

This will use AMD to retrieve the `Contextual` module. Now all that's left is to include the `shaper` functionality into all widgets inside your `<div>`.

First of all, with [`dijit/registry::findWidgets()`](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/registry.html#retrieving-a-widget-from-the-registry-using-the-widgets-dom-node) you can retrieve all widgets inside a specific DOM node, you can use this to retrieve your `dijit/form/MultiSelect` widget in this case:

```js
registry.findWidgets(shaper);
```

Then you can loop over the array of widgets that are found and use [`dojo/_base/lang::mixin()`](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/_base/lang.html#mixin) to extend an object with the contents of another object, for example:

```js
registry.findWidgets(shaper).forEach(function(widget) {
    lang.mixin(widget, shaperModule);
});
```

For example: http://jsfiddle.net/zLv7cvzt/

Though this might not work entirely (what if the module does not exist or what about widgets inside widgets, which `dijit/registry::byId()` does not detect), it does give you an idea of how to achieve it.

---

To answer your second question, if it's feasible or not, I would say that it depends. If you extend a widget with another widget like this, it could really end up with really weird things, because all widgets extend from `dijit/_WidgetBase`, which provides the widget lifecycle, you could mix both widgets their lifecycle.

Also, if you end up doing this and you get an error, it will be really hard to debug this if you're not familiar with the custom code.